# What's the importance of the transcendental numbers in calculus?

Tags: calculus

I have this project in college about trascedental numbers for calculus class and I need to justify why the study of this numbers is relevant for calculus.
If you could give me  a explanation kind of formal about it, I would apreciate it because i need it for a formal LaTeX document, thank you beforehand.

Comment: Well, for a start, $e$ and $\pi$ are very important numbers in calculus and are transcendental.

Comment: Thank you very much, actually, my project 's mostly about e an pi, but, can you be more specififc?

Comment: @lhf They are very important numbers, but their property of being transcendental does not seem so important, at least not in calculus.

Comment: Are you asking why $e$ and $\pi$ are important numbers, or are you asking why it's important that they are transcendental?

Comment: Yowza, not sure what they are getting at.  But the trascendental numbers are the first class of numbers that require that reals be uncountable.  That may be significant in calculating the measure of integrals.

Comment: @bof kind of both. i need to justify why the study of trascendental numbers (in specific e and pi) are relevant in calculus.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you very much, but, do you know anything else about trascendental numbers in calculus, or can you be more specific?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but most of modern analysis is pretty boring without transcendental numbers.  The problem is not that any particular transcendental number is needed, but that the kind of analysis that we would like to perform only really works in a *complete* metric spaces.  The algebraic numbers do not form a complete metric space, thus we have to "fill in the gaps" with transcendental numbers in order to obtain the reals.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for your answer. what I'm asking is just what you say, why do we need the trascendental numbers in calculus (well, more in detail, why do we need the trascendental property in calculus)?

Comment: @ArmandoRosas I'm just going to say it: you don't. You can do calculus perfectly well without distinguishing between algebraic and transcendental numbers (similarly for rational and irrational numbers). The continuum is very important, but classifying individual elements of it is not.

Comment: @ArmandoRosas Because we want a metrically complete space to work in.  If a space is complete, then every Cauchy sequence converges, and we can take limits.  The heart and soul of analysis *is* limits (or, if you prefer, *approximation*).  Without transcendental numbers, limits don't exist in general.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you.  That was what I was trying to get at above---no **particular** number is interesting, but the **continuum** of numbers is vital.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Ok, thanks for attendig my question anyway, but, can you explain to me the cause why only the algebraic numbers don't form a complete metric space? I don't get it too clear, and maybe that could be the justification i need for my project.

Comment: @ArmandoRosas The algebraic numbers contain the rationals (as $p/q$ is a root of $qx - p$). The rationals are dense in the reals, hence so are the algebraic numbers (i.e. their closure is the whole of the real numbers). If the algebraic numbers were complete, then they would be closed, and hence equal to their closure: the real numbers. But transcendental numbers exist, so they're not complete.

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts. It’s basically the web version of $\LaTeX$.

Comment: This is going to sound hand wavy but every algebraic number can be finitely described in discrete bits of information.  To get from one number to another in a continuum there must be smoother transition with no distinct "jumping" from one to another.  This is not possible by any countable system.  ... Phooey.  It's late and I'm tired and I read that an it sounds like mangled claptrap to me, but it is the basis of the difference between any countable set and a continuum.  Maybe someone else can phrase that idea better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The heart and soul of modern analysis (and therefore calculus) is the limit.  Analysis is about approximation—we want to know when things are close together, and if they can be made arbitrarily close under the right conditions.  For example

- $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$, since $\dfrac{1}{n}$ can be made arbitrarily "close" to zero by choosing $n$ "large enough," and
- $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$, since $\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$ can be made arbitrarily "close" to $1$ by choosing $x$ "close enough" to zero.

When we do analysis (or calculus), we would like to be sure that we are working in a space that is "large enough" to ensure that that limits exist.  For example, consider the sequences
$$ \left\{ \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{j^2} \right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\left\{ \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}
$$
Both of these sequences contain only rational numbers and are *Cauchy* over the rationals.  That is, we can make the difference between any two terms as small as we like by choosing those terms far enough along in the sequence.  We would really, really like to use that to say that each sequence converges to some limit, but this is problematic, as neither converges to a limit in the rationals.

In other words, the rational numbers simply aren't a big enough space.  There are sequences of rational numbers that look like they should have limits, but those limits don't exist (as rational numbers).  The fix is to *complete* the space, and throw in enough new objects to make sure that we can find limits.

The construction I have in mind is a bit messy—basically, you consider the set of all possible Cauchy sequences, then quotient out by sequences that should "converge" to the same thing.  The exact details aren't really important.  The point is that the end result is the real numbers.  That is, if you want to take limits of rational sequences, the smallest space that lets you do this is the real numbers.

The real numbers contain all of the rational numbers, and it is fairly easy to show that all of the algebraic numbers are also real (the approach that I have in mind is application of the intermediate value theorem and the bisection method to a minimal polynomial).  On the other hand, it is also possible to show that there are only countably many algebraic numbers, and uncountably many real numbers.  This means that there *must* be transcendental numbers, which must have been introduced when we completed the rationals.

Hence it is not that the transcendentals are necessarily interesting in-and-of themselves, but that their existence is a result of completing the rationals so that we can do analysis.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a big "paradigm shift" between thinking of numbers as quantities ("I have two apples") and points of a continuum ("What are all the possible points between here and Santa Fe").  Xeno intuited this in his motion paradoxes but couldn't resolve it.  Pythagoras insisted quantitative and proportions of quantities was tantamount and all possible values could be expressed that way but was torn apart by the simple $\sqrt{2}$.  Students are to this day confused when they learn the "infinity" of the real numbers is "bigger" than the "infinity" of the whole numbers (and then astonished *again* when they learn that rationals' infinity is the same size as the integers'.)

But as intuitively strange as this may be it is simultaneously intuitively obvious.  We can clearly spread any discrete quantity among any discrete participants by chopping the quantity into bits equally.  And if we are talking about points in continuum we can measure them is a statute distance, say, $1$ mile which which con subdivide into any number of subunits.  But if we were to take a dart and randomly toss it and measure where in lands, the probability of its landing *precisely* on a mile demarcation is...infinitesimal.  For any integer $k$ to land *precisely* on any $\frac 1k$ marker is also infinitesimal.  To which, I suppose one could argue, "Well, since there are an infinite number of demarcation units the sum of an infinite infinitesimals is a solid certainty" but ... well, it doesn't sit well and we seem to be sitting on faith.

But anyway... Cantor's diagonal argument (which can easily be tweaked to fractions just as it is usually tweaked to decimals whereas it was originally meant for sequences) blew that out of the water.

So... "The heart and soul of modern analysis (and therefore calculus) is the limit" as Xander Henderson said so succinctly and eloquently.  We can hone in one through a sequence increasingly smaller demarcations unto  quantities that are "undemarcatable" and it is clear that each demarcation are discrete tuning but the values being honed into, need not be any of demarctable measures.

Now you may be saying "Hey! All your examples above are about *rational* vs. *irrational* numbers; I'm talking about *algebraic* vs. *transcendental*-- you even admitted $\sqrt{2}$ which is *algebraic* was what troubled Pythagoras".  And, you are correct.  But at heart, this is no different.  The rationals are discrete pairing of integers and subdividing them.  The algebraics are a bit more complicated but they are a finite grouping of integers into coefficients and exponents with an algebraic interpretation. Describing the algebraics is still a discrete demarcation.

And the "paradigm shift" and "heart and soul of analysis" is the continuum ...erm.... transcends .... and such discrete demarcations.

Answer (score 2):

Transcendental numbers aren't exactly useful in calculus as far as I know, it's just interesting that they exist.

The basic idea is that transcendental numbers are numbers which cannot be given a name in the language of arithmetic. I can define $\sqrt 2$ using only the language of arithmetic (multiplication, division, addition, subtraction, and the whole numbers) - I can say "$\sqrt 2$ is the (only positive) number which gives $2$ when multiplied by itself". However, in order to define $\pi$, I need the language of geometry - I have to talk about circles.

Of course, I can define $\sqrt 2$ geometrically as well, as the length of the diagonal of a square of side $1$, but I can find an arithmetical way of defining it too. We can't come up with any arithmetic definition of $\pi$.

The formal definition, of course, is that a number is transcendental if it is not a root of any non-zero polynomial with integer coefficients. But "polynomial with integer coefficients" just means "expression that can be written down using $+, \times, -$, a variable $x$, and integer constants". Thus we can say:

> A number $a$ is transcendental iff there is no property expressible with the symbols $+, -, \times, \div$, the integers, and $=$ which is true for $a$ which would not *also* be true for every other number.

Note that I included $\div$, even though in polynomials you normally can't divide by the variable. If you allow dividing by the variable you get [rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function), which can always be written as a quotient of a polynomial, so to be a root of a rational function is the same as to be a root of a polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Handling integer and rational numbers we learn in elementary school. The real numbers come into existence by pouring out "numerical glue" over these rational numbers. In this way a completely homogeneous structure of *real numbers* is created. This structure contains no holes: If $(x_n)_{n\geq1}$ is a sequence of positive rational numbers with $x_n^2\to2$ then the $x_n$ themselves converge to an actual real number we are denoting by $\sqrt{2}$.

The set ${\mathbb R}$ of real numbers contains the set ${\mathbb Q}$ of rational numbers, as well as  any real solutions of polynomial equations $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_0=0$ with real coefficients – the latter are called *algebraic numbers*. But the set ${\mathbb R}$ is much larger and contains (for "set theoretical reasons") infinitely many numbers not mentioned so far, the *transcendental numbers*.

For calculus it is only important that ${\mathbb R}$ is a "complete" and homogeneous structure, consisting of individual objects $\xi$, and working within this structure certain simple and agreeable operations are always allowed.